# Package JavaFX application as single jar in NetBeans

Tags: ant, javafx-2, netbeans-7, executable-jar

I thought I had already seen something like this, but I can't seem to find it at the moment. I'm looking for an Ant-task to combine my application jar, the jars of the libraries and the jars for JavaFX into a single executable jar.

I'm using NetBeans 7.3 and JavaFX 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javafx-setup.html) already will do the job for you, create a `JavaFX` project
`Menu bar -> Run  -> Build Project` will generate a stand-alone executable `jar` file for you .

`JavaFX` provide custom `ant` tasks (used by Netbeans) to build and deploy `JavaFX` projects if you decided to write your own `ant` script.

- [Deploying JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_quick_start.htm#A1278746)

`@jewelsea` has a nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742149/compile-javafx-code-using-ant).

Comment: If I build the project, I have a runnable jar, but not a stand-alone jar: the jars for the libraries are in a folder named lib which needs to be provided with the application jar. I'm looking for something that will unpack all jars and repack them as one jar.

Comment: I'm using [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) even for small sample JavaFX applications.

Comment: Unfortunately, for the latest version it says: "Dropped the 'uber-jar' support and now use a 'lib' directory to avoid a lot of problems people were having". Maybe I'll just do it by hand. I only need it this one time.

Comment: @nvcleemp I just noticed that

Comment: Meanwhile I just did it by hand. I just thought there was an ant task that would save me the time to write the manifest.